# API woes with .Net in C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, exception, connection

I am new to .net and APIs and am currently using .Net 4.5 to connect to an API using rest. The problem I am having is I get an exception thrown back in the return xml that says "Cannot forward request to server with name", "Cannot read data from connection",  Connection reset", full error below.
What is odd is this script works fine on smaller datasets but when the response is large enough, I get that exception from the server thrown back.  What has helped setting the keep alive to true, using httpversion10, and specifying gzip and sendchunked.  I am using advanced rest client to test the server in chrome addins and it returns data fine on there with these larger dataset.  It will not with the script below.  I am suspecting there is a difference in the way I am telling the server to handle my response verses the chrome add in.  Any suggestions on how I improve the performance of this?

This is what the advanced rest client settings look like that work for the Chrome add in.
[image: advanced rest client which is working]

This is the code I have which appears to need changes to make it handle the request/response better.

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"magicalwebsite");


        req.KeepAlive = true;
        req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        req.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 24;
        req.Timeout = 2000000000;
        req.Method = "Post";
        req.Accept = "*/*";
        req.SendChunked = true;
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        //Xml request file for data
        string postData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\yo\Desktop\testtest.txt");

        //sending header and content
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";
        req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("xxxx:xxxxx"));


        Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        //Requesting response of data
        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

       //Grabbing response
        using (Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

            String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

This is the exception I am getting in the xml being thrown back.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response success="false">
  <messages>
    <message key="exception-caught">Caught Exception: Caught Exception:
 Cannot forward request to server with name=prod-euapp01

com.magicalpony.exception.APException: Cannot forward request to server with name=prod-euapp01

    at com.magicalpony.webservices.APIForwarder.forward(APIForwarder.java:105)
    at com.magicalpony.webservices.APIServlet.forwardRequest(APIServlet.java:270)

    at com.magicalpony.webservices.APIServlet.wrongServer(APIServlet.java:253)
    at com.magicalpony.webservices.APIServlet.service(APIServlet.java:124)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.magicalpony.system.WebServiceMonitor.doFilter(WebServiceMonitor.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.
ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

at com.magicalpony.system.HitTracer.doFilter(HitTracer.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)

at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:303)

at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:183)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:169)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.magicalpony.exception.APException:
 Cannot read data from connection
    at com.magicalpony.webservices.NetUtil.readData(NetUtil.java:61)
    at com.magicalpony.webservices.APIForwarder.forward(APIForwarder.java:102)

    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at 
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)

at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)

at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1323)
    at com.magicalpony.webservices.NetUtil.readData(NetUtil.java:58)

... 27 more</message>
  </messages>
</response>
```

Comment: I only have access to the client side of this so not like I can do much with it.  We're connecting to a second party service.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with DNS resolution.

Step 1: Enter your domain name in a browser and see if Server is available.

Step 2: If server is available with domain name then you got to fix the IP Address or DNS resolution.

You can fix this by updating the IP Address in your PC (Follow steps below)

Go to a folder:  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

[image]

Copy and paste "hosts" file to desktop.
Update your host file with your IP Address and domain name.

[image]

Step 3: Copy and Paste hosts file in original folder (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc).

Step 4: Test your API.